# What character/actor combo have appeared in the most movies?

Tags: character

What character/actor combo have appeared in the most movies?

I know Christopher Lee has done at least nine Dracula roles by my count, and a lot of Harry Potter actors reached eight movies in the same role.  Hugh Jackman is about to have his seventh Wolverine, and Connery and Moore both have seven James Bond portrayals, but Desmond Llewellyn racked up 17 movies as Q.  Does anyone beat that?

Comment: I thought Johnny Weissmuller as Tarzan would beat it, but, not even close at 13 movies. He also did another character, Jungle Jim, for another 13 movies.

Comment: Basil Rathbone was close at 16 Sherlock Holmes films

Comment: Dont forget Leonard Nimoy and his Spock role

Comment: Here's a small top in French (but the name of the actor could be enough and the number): http://www.allocine.fr/article/dossiers/cinema/dossier-18592587/

Answer (score 14):

If you count short films as eligible, then Larry Fine, Moe Howard, and Shemp Howard (or Curly - doesn't really matter) outweigh all as the Three Stooges with a combined output in the hundreds.

Comment: Was it really *hundreds*?  They have coalesced in my mind into only about three movies.

Comment: @wallyk - Here is your homework, to count how many times Moe appears in a film as ['Moe'](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0002935/?ref_=sr_1)

Comment: IMDB lists 243 acting roles, and about 11 of those on the first page do not say "Moe", so 233 films would be the first approximation.  Wow!

Comment: Wikipedia says 220 films - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Stooges#Legacy_and_perspective

Answer (score 9):

Mel Blanc (voice of Bugs Bunny) had 1024 acting credits from 1937 through 1990

Comment: I like it. Nothing saying cartoons don't count.

Comment: Unless Mel Blanc was contributing even after his death, hes years of activity ought to be till [1989](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Blanc#Death). Moreover, it'll be unfair to say that Mel Blanc has all credits associated with Bugs Bunny as he was also the voice of Daffy Duck, Bugs Bunny, Tweety Bird among many others.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: 1990 is presumably because the credit is associated with the year of release of the work, not the year the voice actor sat in a studio and did it. So yes, he was contributing even after his death, but as you point out calling that a year of "activity" would be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Right up near the top would be Mickey Rooney in the Andy Hardy series.  There were 16 full length films and one short.  Mickey Rooney probably appeared in more films than anyone else, over 320, usually in the leading part.